# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar información de mi base de datos local en mysql en los TextView de Android Studio?

Tags: php, java, android-studio, xampp

tengo mi base de datos local creada en XAMPP y ya cuento con la conexión PHP

```dart
<?php
$hostname='127.0.0.1';
$database='opdm';
$username='root';
$password='';

$conexion=new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
if($conexion->connect_errno){
 echo "el sitio esta experimentado problemas";
}
?>
```

también cuento ya con el PHP de mi consulta

```dart
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$cuenta=$_GET['cuenta'];

$consulta = "select * from servicio_db where cuenta ='$cuenta'";
$resultado =$conexion -> query ($consulta);

while ($row=$resultado -> fetch_array()) {
    # code...
    $cuenta = array_map('utf8_encode',$row);
}
echo json_encode($cuenta);
$resultado -> close();

?>
```

he probado ya que funcione mi conexión y mi archivo de consulta, me arroja la información al meter el id hasta ahí no tengo ningún problema ahora bien eh creado en Android Studio la interfaz asi como declarar que mi aplicacion se conectara a internet por medio de:  y agregando al modulo: implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1' al momento de agregar al EditText el id a buscar quiero que la infromacion se muestre en cada uno de los campos de los TextView pero no se muestra la información.

```dart
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nombre, calle, colonia, codigopostal, fechalimitedepago, montoapagar, numerodecuenta, pagodomiciliado, ruta, numerodemedidor, suministroirregular, cumplido, grupovulnerable, fechadelecturaanterior, viviendas, locales, tipodeusuario, lecturaanterior, lecturaactual, consumo, diametro, basecalculo, anomalia;
    Button consultar;
    EditText cuenta;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cuenta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cuenta);
        nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        calle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calle);
        colonia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colonia);
        codigopostal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codigopostal);
        fechalimitedepago = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fechalimitedepago);
        montoapagar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.montoapagar);
        numerodecuenta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numerocuenta);
        pagodomiciliado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagodomiciliado);
        ruta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ruta);
        numerodemedidor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numerodemedidor);
        suministroirregular = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suministroirregular);
        cumplido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cumplido);
        grupovulnerable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grupovulnerable);
        fechadelecturaanterior = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fechadelecturaanterior);
        viviendas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viviendas);
        locales = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locales);
        tipodeusuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipodeusuario);
        lecturaanterior = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lecturaanterior);
        lecturaactual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lecturaactual);
        consumo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.consumo);
        diametro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diametro);
        basecalculo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.basedecalculo);
        anomalia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anomalia);
        consultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consultar);


        consultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                consultarServicio("http://192.168.120.59:8080/opdm/servicio.php?cuenta=" + cuenta.getText() + "");
            }
        });


    }

    private void consultarServicio(String URL) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("nombre", nombre.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("calle", calle.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("colonia", colonia.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("codigopostal", codigopostal.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("fechalimitedepago", fechalimitedepago.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("montoapagar", montoapagar.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("numerodecuenta", numerodecuenta.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("pagodomiciliado", pagodomiciliado.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("ruta", ruta.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("numerodemedidor", numerodemedidor.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("suministroirregular", suministroirregular.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("cumplido", cumplido.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("grupovulnerable", grupovulnerable.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("fechadelecturaanterior", fechadelecturaanterior.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("viviendas", viviendas.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("locales", locales.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("tipodeusuario", tipodeusuario.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("lecturaanterior", lecturaanterior.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("lecturaactual", lecturaactual.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("consumo", consumo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("diametro", diametro.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("basecalculo", basecalculo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("anomalia", anomalia.getText().toString());

                return parametros;
            }

        };
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void buscarservicio(String URL) {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        nombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));
                        calle.setText(jsonObject.getString("calle"));
                        colonia.setText(jsonObject.getString("colonia"));
                        codigopostal.setText(jsonObject.getString("codigopostal"));
                        fechalimitedepago.setText(jsonObject.getString("fechalimitedepago"));
                        montoapagar.setText(jsonObject.getString("montoapagar"));
                        numerodecuenta.setText(jsonObject.getString("numerodecuenta"));
                        pagodomiciliado.setText(jsonObject.getString("pagodomiciliado"));
                        ruta.setText(jsonObject.getString("ruta"));
                        numerodemedidor.setText(jsonObject.getString("numerodemedidor"));
                        suministroirregular.setText(jsonObject.getString("suministroirregular"));
                        cumplido.setText(jsonObject.getString("cumplido"));
                        grupovulnerable.setText(jsonObject.getString("grupovulnerable"));
                        fechadelecturaanterior.setText(jsonObject.getString("fechadelecturaanterior"));
                        viviendas.setText(jsonObject.getString("viviendas"));
                        locales.setText(jsonObject.getString("locales"));
                        tipodeusuario.setText(jsonObject.getString("tipodeusuario"));
                        lecturaanterior.setText(jsonObject.getString("lecturaanterior"));
                        lecturaactual.setText(jsonObject.getString("lecturaactual"));
                        consumo.setText(jsonObject.getString("consumo"));
                        diametro.setText(jsonObject.getString("diametro"));
                        basecalculo.setText(jsonObject.getString("basecalculo"));
                        anomalia.setText(jsonObject.getString("anomalia"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error al hacer debug?

Comment: ¿Te muestra `OPERACION EXITOSA`? Entonces desde el `onResponse` puedes obtener los datos que hay en `response` para mostrarlo en el `TextView`. Si no muestra éxito, entonces,  ¿falla? Si falla, ¿cuál es el error? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega la traza del error.

Comment: si me muestra operación exitosa, pero no muestra nada al igual si solo presiono el botón sin agregar el id a obtener igual me marca operación exitosa el código no me marca errores, se supone que al ingresar el id y presionar el botón debería mostrarme la información de la base de datos en cada EditText gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que *debería* mostrarla? Para que la muestre debes hacer que la muestre y no lo estás haciendo. Cuando la peitición tiene éxito entra aquí: `public void onResponse(String response) {` y los datos que traiga del servidor estarán en `response`. Entonces tienes que trabajar `response` para mostrar los datos que quieres y mostrarlos en el `TextView`. No estás haciendo eso. ¿Comprendes lo que te estoy explicando?

Comment: ah ok entonces debo trabajar sobre response para que me muestre los datos que quiero obtener

Comment: Correcto. Si quieres ver la respuesta del servidor en el Toast, puede poner esto: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA "+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Ahí deberás ver lo que ha respondido el servidor. Pero tienes que trabajarlo. Dado que al parecer mandas un JSON, deberás convertirlo a `JSONObject` para leerlo de una forma organizada. O puedes cambiar el tipo de Request de Volley, de String a JSONObject. Pero mejor prueba primero si realmente está respondiendo bien y trayendo los datos.